# node.js sql server driver - is it still being actively developed?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, node-sqlserver

The Microsoft node.js sql server driver (https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver) has not had any  commits for 11 months. Anyone know what's going on with this effort? My company is using it actively, but has run across some issues that led me to the repo and the discovery that it seems to have been abandoned. Lots of open bugs also.

Should we give up on this driver and try another? Any recommendations?

Microsoft, please weigh in here.

Comment: Just from binging around, [`tedious`](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) might be worth looking at and certainly has more current activity.

Comment: There is no alternative. If Microsoft says the driver is done then it's done. The "bugs" you have encountered are clearly features or else they would have fixed them ;)

Comment: I will forward this URL to a few folks to try and see what I can hear back about.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the Microsoft main contributor and he was very helpful, although he did admit that officially MS has never declared one way or the other if they were going to continue support. Guess we'll wait and see.

In regards to my original problem - this info may help someone.

I was using queryRaw and listening for events to build the response. This method allows the user to submit multiple sql queries in one request (just separate them with ;). A large text datatype field was getting truncated and I couldn't figure out why. Turns out that the 'more' parameter that is supplied by the driver means that you must concatinate the return data.

Lots of trial and error when figuring out this driver.